# Uploading Image to Cloudinary API with PHP

Tags: php, html, api, cloudinary

I am new at this... but I am trying to upload an `Image` to my Cloudinary API Account by using `PHP`. However I've been receiving the following errors; even though I have given an `API_KEY` and `API_Secret`.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Must supply api_key' in C:\xampp\htdocs\-\php\Cloudinary.php:786 
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\-\php\Uploader.php(247): 
Cloudinary::sign_request(Array, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\-\php\Uploader.php(62): 
Cloudinary\Uploader::call_api('upload', Array, Array, 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\ph...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\-\php\addProverbs.php(12): 
Cloudinary\Uploader::upload('C:\\xampp\\tmp\\ph...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\-\php\Cloudinary.php on line 786
```

In my `PHP` I have provided my details as shown below...

```
<?php
    $prov = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    require_once("connection.php");
    require 'Cloudinary.php';
    require 'Uploader.php';
    require 'Api.php';
    $connection = connectToMySQL();

    $proverbDescription = $prov->proverbDescription;
    $proverbNumber = $prov->proverbNumber;  
    $imgPath = $prov->imgPath;
    $cloudUpload = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($_FILES["imgPath"]['tmp_name']);

    \Cloudinary::config(array(
    "cloud_name" => "xxxxxx",
    "api_key" => "xxxxxxx", //hidden for obvious reasons
    "api_secret" => "xxxxxxxx"
    ));
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        print_r($_FILES["imgPath"]);
        $cloudUpload = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($_FILES["imgPath"]['tmp_name']);
        print_r($cloudUpload);
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_proverb (proverbDescription, proverbNumber, imgPath) VALUES ('$proverbDescription', '$proverbNumber', '$cloudUpload')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
         or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0){
            $success = true;
    }else{
            $success = false;
    }           
?>
```

This is my `HTML` form which contains the `Image Upload` and 2 `textboxes`.

```
<form id="demo" class="collapse" action="php/addProverbs.php" ng-submit="addProverb(prov)" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label>Image:</label>
         <input type="file" ng-model="prov.imgPath" name="imgPath" id="imgPath" accept="image/*">
    <label>Proverb Description:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="prov.proverbDescription" ><br><br>
    <label>Proverb Number:</label>                          
        <input type="text" ng-model="prov.proverbNumber"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
    <a href="#/proverbs">See your post</a>
</form>
```

Sorry for a basic question but I am quite new to this.

Thanks alot!